# do...while loop not displaying what I want

Tags: c++

So basically I have been working on this one loop for about 7 hours today.  It is not behaving how I believe it should.  When I enter a fail state with the cin (row is a char, column is an int, so if for instance I enter aa1 instead of a1) it will cout invalidCoord twice before asking for a new coord.

```
do
{
    confirmShot = false;
    validShot = false;
    failShot = false;
    cout << enterCoord;
    cin >> row >> column;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cout << invalidCoord << endl;
        failShot = false;
        continue;
    }
    if (failShot == true)
    {
        row = toupper(row);
        xCoord = column - 1;
        yCoord = static_cast<int>(row - 'A');
        if(xCoord > 9 || xCoord < 0 || yCoord > 9 || yCoord < 0)
        {
            cout << invalidCoord << endl;
            validShot = false;
        }
        else
        {
            validShot = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
    currentTile = tileToSymbol(computerBoard[xCoord][yCoord]);
    if (validShot == true)
    {
        switch(currentTile)
        {
            case '~':
            case 'a':
            case 'b':
            case 's':
            case 'd':
            case 'p':
                cout << "You have already shot at " << row << column << "." << '\n'
                    << "Please pick a new coordinate!" << endl;
                validShot = false;
                confirmShot = false;
                break;
            default:
                confirmShot = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
while(!confirmShot);
```

Output:

```
Your shot:  Enter the coordinates for a shot (e.g. B2) cc2
Invalid coordinates!
Pick a row value between A and J
and a column value between 1 and 10.
Enter the coordinates for a shot (e.g. B2) Enter the coordinates for a shot (e.g. B2) cc2
Invalid coordinates!
Pick a row value between A and J
and a column value between 1 and 10.
Enter the coordinates for a shot (e.g. B2) Enter the coordinates for a shot (e.g. B2) c2
Enter the coordinates for a shot (e.g. B2) c2
```

Additionally, I cannot figure out how to get the do...while loop to exit anymore.  It used to exit fine before I realized that I had to handle the failstate if someone entered a non-integer as the second character.

I added the "continue" code because someone I was talking to said I needed it to skip to the next section, and if I remove it, the program locks up, although before I tried to handle the failstate I did not have the continue code in there, and it worked just fine.

I really just need to get this loop working correctly, but I've exhausted my ability.  How can I handle the failstate, keep invalidCoord from display twice (I honestly have no idea why it is doing that), exit the loop after receiving valid entry, and save the day?

Comment: I mentioned in the post that row is a char and column is an int.
Full code is here:
https://repl.it/repls/DiscreteAltruisticNighthawk

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `cin.clear()` does. It just clears the error flag. The invalid input is still there. It doesn't like you've written code that does anything like what I suspect you want to do. Do you want to read in a line of input and see if it contains exactly two characters?

Comment: Don't use `>>` for input. It's basically `scanf`.

Comment: @melpomene - I have no idea what you mean, but that is exactly how we are being taught.  cin >>  and cout <<.  I'd have to tell my instructor that he is wrong, and considering my level of "expertise" that would be foolish.

Comment: @melpomene, you should prefer `>>` over `scanf`. The former is type-safe.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x So is `scanf` if you enable compiler warnings. Neither of them is safe with `char *` (hello, buffer overflows), and `>>` offers even less control over the input than `scanf`. They're both awful for user input.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - No, I am trying to get input for a game of battleship, with valid coordinates ranging from A1-A10 all the way to J1-J10.  The cin should get a char variable for row (A-J) and an int variable for column (1-10).  The failstate detection is supposed to just make sure that an integer is the second entry.

Comment: @melpomene, sure but warnings are not mandated and no one here is talking about reading into `char*`s. telling OP to not use `>>` doesn't help

Comment: @vu1p3n0x How doesn't it help when `>>` is exactly the problem? If they'd used `std::getline`, we wouldn't even be here.

Comment: @melpomene post an answer then, using `getline` is fine but it needs more explanation than a comment can provide

Comment: @n.m. - What do you mean it doesn't match the code?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake

Comment: @n.m.- No worries, I have been working on this do ... while loop for over 10 hours now.

Comment: @JiveDadson - Thanks for your opinion.  However since you haven't actually attempted to answer the question you'll excuse me when I don't rush to throw out a 95% working code for something that simply doesn't exist.  (andYesWeMustUseCamelCase).

Answer (score 1):

I may be over simplifying it, and please comment if I am wrong but I think the error is simply in your if statements.

It appears as though `if (failShot == true)` never gets called since `failShot` was initialised as false, and only gets updated as false again whenever you check  `if (cin.fail())`. If I am understanding this correctly, you want `if (failShot == true)` to get called if your `cin` does not fail. In this case, initialising failShot as True would fix your error.

Try changing:

```
    failShot = false;
```

To:

```
    failShot = true;
```

Comment: That was one of the issues I was seeing, but I had specifically changed it to do that while trying to get rid of the bug where even after the error state it would display the "Invalid Coords" but then go on to execute the rest of the loop as if there was no error state as well as exit the do...while loop.  I was trying to isolate the program to only executing a small section of the code by explicitly telling it to NOT execute the rest every step of the way.

Comment: Well then it would **Never** exit the loop. You only exit if `confirmShot` is true, `confirmShot` can only be true if `validShot` is true, and valid shot can only be true if `failShot` is true... so by making failShot never true you are making the loop endless

Comment: It seems you have tried to single out the issue but raised another one entirely. I suggest putting it back the way it was and showing us the original error/output. Then maybe we can better know how to help

Answer (score 0):

ok, your problem is the understanding of the `std::cin` object.

this is how it works

`std::cin` starts at position `pos_type p = -1` then increment this position as it fetches chars from the keyboard buffer, when it encounter an error in parsing the entered chars, it sets the position to `eof`, so when next time it runs, it will return `eof` then do nothing.

to illustrate this in your code, insert this snippet under: `cin<<row<<column;`

```
cin << row << column ;
cout << "p =" << cin.tellg();
```

it will output the following (only interesting part is printed here)

```
// when you enter for expel: c1 - which is correct input, it prints
p = 2; // advanced two position in the buffer until EOF
// when you enter wrong input: cc1 - it prints
p =-1;
// next run just after the error message, it will print
p = 3;//this number is the number of character read last time and it coincide with EOF
// right after, it will prompt you for another input
```

which means `std::cin` needs to consume all the character in the buffer then sets the position indicator to -1, then start extracting character again.

and that's exactly why you have a duplicated message. So how to fix it?

this is an ugly hack:

```
//inside the loop under
cin.clear()
cin.seekg(0); // rewind...uuurrrgg, ugly!! but it works
```

what I suggest is to restructure your code. Use Boolean logic to design a beautiful code flow chart. Error like this in a code base, means that the code is more a spaghetti code rather than a well written code.

Do your best, Good luck!